# Impossibility to show in a label the text of an object

Tags: xcode, object, text, label

My objective is to show in a label the text of an object of a custom class called Files. Here is Files.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Files : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;

@end
```

This is Files.m :

```
#import "Files.h"

@implementation Files

@dynamic title;
@dynamic text;
@end
```

Here is the .h file of my app. the label is called trackName:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Files.h"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

{
    Files *plainpalais;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *trackName;


-(Files*) chooseFile;


@end
```

This is the .m file of the app:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize trackName;

-(Files*)chooseFile
{
    return plainpalais;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    plainpalais.text=@"hello";
    plainpalais.title=@"plainpalais";
    trackName.text=plainpalais.title;


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTrackName:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}


@end
```

The problem is that the label trackName doesn't show plainpalais...

Thanks for help !

PS: I'm a beginner so this is probably a basic mistake.

Comment: Have you linked `trackName` to the UI object using Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes ! I think the problem lies in how I declared the Files class and stuff. In fact if I ask to do trackName.text=@"hello"; it works !!

Answer (score 1):

You have used `@dynamic` in your `Files.m` implementation which tells the compiler that you'll provide getters/setters for these properties at a later time, i.e. using the Objective-C runtime.

I suspect you want to use `@synthesize` rather than `@dynamic`.  For example,

```
#import "Files.h"

@implementation Files

@synthesize title;
@synthesize text;

@end
```

Also you haven't actually created a `Files` object in the code you have given us.  The `chooseFile` method appears to be returning  a `nil` object (assuming you haven't initialised `plainpalais` somewhere else).  Perhaps you should initialise `plainpalais` in an `init` method, e.g.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        plainpalias = [[Files alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don't forget to `release` this object in `dealloc` (if you aren't using ARC).

Comment: thank you for helping... I'm trying right now to fix it the way you said.

Comment: Thanks again! I have another question: where am I supposed to initialize plainpalais ? Before, I did Files *plainpalais; in the interface of the .h file...

Comment: `Files *plainpalias;` in the .h file is simply creating a place to store the object. It doesn't actually create the object.  You could initialise it by adding the `init` method I show above to the .m file of your app.